# NullPointerException in `BluetoothAdapter` when startService() is invoked

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9s15.png) I'm getting null point exception in `Bluetooth` when I'm starting a service.

LiveFragment.class

```
public class LiveFragment extends Fragment {


    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =null;
    public BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = null;
    private PowerManager powerManager = null;
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    private boolean isServiceBound;
    private boolean preRequisites = true;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private Context c;
    private AbstractGatewayService ab;

    protected ImageView blue_onoffBut, gps_Button, obd_inidca, ss_button, bluetooth_indicator, gps_indicator,obd_connectButt;
    protected TextView ss_Status,btStatusTextView,obdStatusTextView,gpsStatusTextView;
    private LinearLayout vv;
    protected BluetoothSocket sock = null;

    public LiveFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private final Runnable mQueueCommands = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Runnable mQueueCommands ()");
            if (ab != null && ab.isRunning() && ab.queueEmpty()) {
                queueCommands();
            }
            // run again in period defined in preferences
            new Handler().postDelayed(mQueueCommands, 4000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_live, container, false);

        blue_onoffBut = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.blutooth_butoon);
        gps_Button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gps_button);
        obd_inidca = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.obd_Indicator);
        ss_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(ssButton);
        gps_indicator = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gps_indicator);
        bluetooth_indicator = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_indicator);
        obd_connectButt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Obd_Connect_Button);

        ss_Status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusTx);
        btStatusTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.blue);
        obdStatusTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.obd);
        gpsStatusTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gps);
        vv = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_live_layout);

        ss_Status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            bluetooth_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_circle);
        } else {
            bluetooth_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
        }

        gps_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
                if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
                    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
                }
                else {
                    showToast("Already GPS is ON");
                }
            }
        });

        blue_onoffBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
                    showToast("Bluetooth Turned ON"+"\n"+"Connect Your OBD now");
                    bluetooth_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_circle);
                    mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(getActivity(), mHandler);

                    if (mChatService != null) {
                        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
                        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
                            // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                            mChatService.start();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    obd_inidca.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
                    showToast("Bluetooth Turned OFF");
                    bluetooth_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
                }
            }
        });

        ss_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() && mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    startLiveData();
                } else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    showToast("Turn ON Bluetooth to Continue");
                }
                else if (!(mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED)){
                    showToast("Select your OBD to Start ");
                }
            }
        });

        obd_connectButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
                }
                else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                    showToast("Turn ON Bluetooth to Connect OBD");
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private ServiceConnection serviceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            Log.d(TAG, className.toString() + " service is bound");
            isServiceBound = true;
            ab = ((AbstractGatewayService.AbstractGatewayServiceBinder) binder).getService();
            ab.setContext(getActivity());
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting live data");
            try {
                ab.startService();
                if (preRequisites)
                    btStatusTextView.setText("Connected");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failure Starting live data");
                btStatusTextView.setText("Connection failed");
                doUnbindService();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            Log.d(TAG, "CloneNotSupportedException ");
            return super.clone();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d(TAG, className.toString() + " service is unbound");
            isServiceBound = false;
        }
    };

    public static String LookUpCommand(String txt) {
        Log.d(TAG, "LookUpCommand() ");
        for (AvailableCommandNames item : AvailableCommandNames.values()) {
            if (item.getValue().equals(txt)) return item.name();
        }
        return txt;
    }

    public void updateTextView(final TextView view, final String txt) {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateTextView() ");
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                view.setText(txt);
            }
        });
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void stateUpdate(ObdCommandJob job) {
        final String cmdName = job.getCommand().getName();
        String cmdResult = "";
        final String cmdID = LookUpCommand(cmdName);
        Log.d(TAG, "stateUpdate() ");
        if (job.getState().equals(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.EXECUTION_ERROR)) {
            cmdResult = job.getCommand().getResult();
            if (cmdResult != null && isServiceBound) {
                obdStatusTextView.setText(cmdResult.toLowerCase());
            }
        } else if (job.getState().equals(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.BROKEN_PIPE)) {
            if (isServiceBound)
                stopLiveData();
        } else if (job.getState().equals(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.NOT_SUPPORTED)) {
            cmdResult = "NA";
        } else {
            cmdResult = job.getCommand().getFormattedResult();
            if (isServiceBound)
                obdStatusTextView.setText("Receiving data...");
        }
        cmdResult.replace("NODATA", "0");
        if (vv.findViewWithTag(cmdID) != null) {
            TextView existingTV = (TextView) vv.findViewWithTag(cmdID);
            existingTV.setText(cmdResult);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "No Bluetooth Feature in Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            gps_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            bluetooth_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "ObdReader");

        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        if ( manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            gps_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_circle);
        } else {
            gps_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
        }
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (mChatService != null) {
                // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
                if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
                    // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                    mChatService.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "Pausing..");
        releaseWakeLockIfHeld();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toast.cancel();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       /* unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);*/
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseWakeLockIfHeld();
        if (mChatService != null) {
            mChatService.stop();
        }
        if (isServiceBound) {
            doUnbindService();
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
        showToast("Take Care!");
    }

    private void startLiveData() {
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting live data..");
            ss_Status.setText("Stop");
            ss_Status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            wakeLock.acquire();

            ss_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ss_Status.setText("Go Live");
                    ss_Status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                    stopLiveData();
                }
            });

            doBindService();

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver((broadcastReceiver), new IntentFilter(OBD_GATEWAY_SERVICE));

            new Handler().post(mQueueCommands);
        }
    }

    private void stopLiveData() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping live data..");
        releaseWakeLockIfHeld();
        new Handler().removeCallbacks(mQueueCommands);

        ss_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ss_Status.setText("Go Live");
                ss_Status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                startLiveData();
            }
        });

        doUnbindService();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    private void queueCommands() {
        Log.d(TAG, "LiveFragment queueCommands() ");
        if (isServiceBound) {
            for (ObdCommand Command : ObdConfig.getCommands()) {
                if (prefs.getBoolean(Command.getName(), true))
                    ab.queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(Command));
            }
        }
    }

    private void doBindService() {
        if (!isServiceBound) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Binding OBD service..");
            if (preRequisites) {
                btStatusTextView.setText("Connecting.....");
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),ObdGatewayService.class);
                getActivity().bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void doUnbindService() {
        if (isServiceBound) {
            if (ab.isRunning()) {
                ab.stopService();
                if (preRequisites)
                    btStatusTextView.setText("Ready...");
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Unbinding OBD service..");
            getActivity().unbindService(serviceConn);
            isServiceBound = false;
            obdStatusTextView.setText("Disconnected");
        }
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            obd_inidca.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_circle);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                obd_inidca.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange_circle);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    obd_inidca.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_circle);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    // save the connected device's name
                    mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Connected to "
                                + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        obd_inidca.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_circle);
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
                // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        connectDevice(data, true);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) throws IOException {
        // Get the device MAC address
        String address = data.getExtras()
                .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object
        BluetoothDevice dev = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        // Attempt to connect to the device
        mChatService.connect(dev, secure);
    }.
```

**This is ObdGateway service class:**

```
public class ObdGatewayService extends AbstractGatewayService {

    private static final String TAG = ObdGatewayService.class.getName();

    @Inject
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    private BluetoothDevice dev = null;
    private BluetoothSocket sock = null;
    private BluetoothChatService mChatservice = null;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter =null;


    public final static String JOB_NAME_STAMP = "Name";
    public final static String JOB_STATE_STAMP = "State";
    public final static String JOB_RESULT_STAMP = "Result";
    public final static String JOB_FORMATED_RESULT_STAMP = "Formated REsult";
    public final static String OBD_GATEWAY_SERVICE = "com.samplersoft.saz.Obd.ObdGatewayService";

    public void startService() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting service..");

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // get the remote Bluetooth device
        if(mChatservice.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED){
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "No Bluetooth device selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // log error
            Log.e(TAG, "No Bluetooth device has been selected.");

            stopService();
            throw new IOException();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Bluetooth discovery.");
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                startObdConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(
                        TAG,
                        "There was an error while establishing connection. -> "
                                + e.getMessage()
                );

                // in case of failure, stop this service.
                stopService();
                throw new IOException();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startObdConnection() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting OBD connection..");
        isRunning = true;

            if(mChatservice.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED){
                // Let's configure the connection.
                Log.d(TAG, "Queueing jobs for connection configuration..");
                queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new ObdResetCommand()));
                try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new EchoOffCommand()));
                queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new EchoOffCommand()));
                queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new LineFeedOffCommand()));
                queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new TimeoutCommand(62)));

                // Get protocol from preferences
                queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.valueOf("AUTO"))));

                // Job for returning dummy data
                queueJob(new ObdCommandJob(new AmbientAirTemperatureCommand()));

                queueCounter = 0L;
                Log.d(TAG, "Initialization jobs queued.");

            }
            else {
                stopService();
                throw new IOException();
            }

        }

    @Override
    public void queueJob(ObdCommandJob job) {
        // This is a good place to enforce the imperial units option
        //job.getCommand().useImperialUnits(prefs.getBoolean(ConfigActivity.IMPERIAL_UNITS_KEY, false));

        // Now we can pass it along
        super.queueJob(job);
    }
    protected void executeQueue() throws InterruptedException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Executing queue..");
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            ObdCommandJob job = null;
            try {
                job = jobsQueue.take();

                // log job
                Log.d(TAG, "Taking job[" + job.getId() + "] from queue..");

                if (job.getState().equals(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.NEW)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Job state is NEW. Run it..");
                    job.setState(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.RUNNING);
                    if (sock.isConnected()) {
                        job.getCommand().run(sock.getInputStream(), sock.getOutputStream());
                    } else {
                        job.setState(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.EXECUTION_ERROR);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Can't run command on a closed socket.");
                    }
                } else
                    // log not new job
                    Log.e(TAG,
                            "Job state was not new, so it shouldn't be in queue. BUG ALERT!");
            } catch (InterruptedException i) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (UnsupportedCommandException u) {
                if (job != null) {
                    job.setState(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.NOT_SUPPORTED);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Command not supported. -> " + u.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException io) {
                if (job != null) {
                    if(io.getMessage().contains("Broken pipe"))
                        job.setState(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.BROKEN_PIPE);
                    else
                        job.setState(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.EXECUTION_ERROR);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "IO error. -> " + io.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (job != null) {
                    job.setState(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.EXECUTION_ERROR);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to run command. -> " + e.getMessage());
            }

            ObdCommandJob job2 = job;
            if(job2 !=null)
                EventBus.getDefault().post(job2);
        }
    }
    public void stopService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping service..");

        jobsQueue.clear();
        isRunning = false;

        if (sock != null)
            // close socket
            try {
                sock.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        // kill service
        stopSelf();
    }
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }
}.
```

This is `Abstract Class` where service method gets called from from `Livefragment Class` from `serivceConnection()`.

```
public abstract class AbstractGatewayService extends RoboService {

    private static final String TAG = AbstractGatewayService.class.getName();
    private final IBinder binder = new AbstractGatewayServiceBinder();
    protected Context ctx;
    protected boolean isRunning = false;
    protected Long queueCounter = 0L;
    protected BlockingQueue<ObdCommandJob> jobsQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                executeQueue();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                t.interrupt();
            }
        }
    });

    protected LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating service..");
       final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        t.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service created.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Destroying service...");
        t.interrupt();
        broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Service destroyed.");
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public boolean queueEmpty() {
        return jobsQueue.isEmpty();
    }

    public void queueJob(ObdCommandJob job) {
        queueCounter++;
        Log.d(TAG, "Adding job[" + queueCounter + "] to queue..");

        job.setId(queueCounter);
        try {
            jobsQueue.put(job);
            Log.d(TAG, "Job queued successfully.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            job.setState(ObdCommandJob.ObdCommandJobState.QUEUE_ERROR);
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to queue job.");
        }
    }

    public void setContext(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
    }

    abstract protected void executeQueue() throws InterruptedException;

    abstract public void startService() throws IOException;

    abstract public void stopService();

    public class AbstractGatewayServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public AbstractGatewayService getService() {
            return AbstractGatewayService.this;
        }
    }
}.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because in `class ObdGatewayService` your class member `mChatservice` is not the same as `mChatservice` in `class LiveFragment`
They are just **different** member variables

`mChatservice` gets assigned like this in your Fragment

```
mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(getActivity(), mHandler);
```

You need to pass this reference to `ObdGatewayService` 's `startService()` like this where ever you are instantiating/invoking it:-

```
ObdGatewayService ogs;
....
ogs.startservice(mChatservice); // This is fragment's member reference
```

And in `ObdGatewayService` you have to assign it accordingly:-

```
public void startService(BluetoothChatService _mChatservice) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting service..");
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mChatservice = _mChatservice  //Assignment YOU ARE MISSING THIS
        .......
        .......
}
```

Comment: But the start service is method is getting called by using the reference of abstract class which I have mentioned in the question?? Do you want me to directly call ogs.startSerivce() ?

Comment: I see , then pass the reference here `ab.startService(mChatservice)` And add the member in abstarct class

Comment: yeah Thank you so much! it's working

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Can you pls accept- Upvote the ans

Comment: done! @Zakir but I'm getting new Null pointer exception again in Live Fragment at java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                               at com.samplersoft.alive.LiveFragment.stateUpdate(LiveFragment.java:258)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: it's showing null at cmd.result (in thread method).. please go through it and help?

Comment: it is showing that error saying greenbot has no Subscribers!

Comment: Suggest to post a new question removing Bluetooth tag..

Comment: Btw your `cmdResult.replace("NODATA", "0")` is not going to work you should assign it to a new string:- `String cmdResult1 = cmdResult.replace("NODATA", "0")` and setText it for the no data case

Comment: And pls accept-upvote this ans for your `startService()` fix !

Comment: yeah I will but right now I have only 5 reputation I need 15 to do that!

Comment: I think you can "accept" with even 1

Comment: I tried doing but it is asking 15reputations, btw thanks a lot for the help!